# How can i disable variable with locals()?

Tags: django, sqlite

```
acc = accounts.objects.get(twitterid=userid)

        if acc:
            accountcredit = acc.credit
            return render_to_response('twitter_auth/info.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

'QuerySet' object has no attribute

İ don want return "acc" variable with locals(), what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
del acc
```

But it is better to use a code like this

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
try:
    acc = accounts.objects.get(twitterid=userid)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    <<when not found>>
else:
    accountcredit = acc.credit
    return render_to_response('twitter_auth/info.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

p.s. locals() is useful for creating small views, use context={}

Comment: The usefulness of `del` in this case is just about zero. He'd end up with a bunch of `del` statements at the bottom of his code cluttering and not making much sense, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use `locals()`, create your own context dictionary and pass that on to the template.

```
context = {
    'accountcredit': whatever_data_you_want
}
return render_to_response('twitter_auth/info.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Also, using `locals()` is generally a bad idea since you're passing with *everything* that your function has defined as variables, which can lead some unexpected behaviour and is generally considered unsafe.